# Travelling salesman unexpected segmentation fault

Tags: c, segmentation-fault, traveling-salesman

I'm trying to implement my own depth-first search algorithm for the travelling salesman problem in C99, but I'm getting an unexpected segmentation fault.

I have a small series of nodes corresponding (roughly) to places in the UK with symmetric paths between them. The problem occurs early on in the `newNode()` method, where I create a new node and set up its initial state. This involves creating an array of paths for the node which will specify connected nodes and the "distance" between them, in which the node element of each path is initialised to NULL. The arrays are much larger then I need for the example graph I've implemented currently (see `MAX_PATHS`), so it's easy to expand later.

The `paths` array can contain 16 elements in this case. The FOR loop which initialises this array raises a segmentation fault when `i = 3`. The reason why completely eludes me. I have added some output from `gdb` below the code. Hopefully it helps, or you may prefer to use your own methods.

Thanks; any help would be greatly appreciated!

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define NODES 4
#define MAX_PATHS 16

typedef struct _node_t node_t;
typedef struct _path_t path_t;

struct _node_t
{
    char name[64];
    struct _path_t* paths;
};

struct _path_t
{
    struct _node_t* node;
    int dist;
};

node_t* nodes[NODES];

node_t* newNode(char* name)
{
    node_t* toReturn = (node_t*) malloc(sizeof(node_t*));

    if (toReturn == NULL)
    {
        perror("malloc");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    printf("toReturn (%p)\n", toReturn);

    strcpy(toReturn->name, name);

    toReturn->paths = (path_t*) malloc(sizeof(path_t) * MAX_PATHS);

    if (toReturn->paths == NULL)
    {
        perror("malloc");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    printf("toReturn->paths (%p)\n", toReturn->paths);

    for (int i = 0; i < MAX_PATHS; i++)
        toReturn->paths[i].node = NULL; /* !!! */

    return toReturn;
}

void addPath(node_t* node1, node_t* node2, int dist)
{
    int i = 0;

    while (i < MAX_PATHS)
    {
        if (node1->paths[i].node == NULL)
        {
            node1->paths[i].node = node2;
            node1->paths[i].dist = dist;
            break;
        }

        i++;
    }

    if (i == MAX_PATHS)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Ran out of paths!!\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    i = 0;

    while (i < MAX_PATHS)
    {
        if (node2->paths[i].node == NULL)
        {
            node2->paths[i].node = node1;
            node2->paths[i].dist = dist;
            break;
        }

        i++;
    }

    if (i == MAX_PATHS)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Ran out of paths!!\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
}

int getNodeIndex(node_t* node)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < NODES; i++)
        if (nodes[i] == node)
            return i;

    return -1;
}

void depthFirstSearch(node_t* node, int* visited, int depth, int length)
{
    printf("%s\n", node->name);

    int i = 0; /* Path pointer */

    int thisVisited[NODES];
    memcpy(thisVisited, visited, sizeof(int) * NODES);

    /* Set this node as visited */

    visited[getNodeIndex(node)] = 1;

    /* Now traverse all connected nodes that haven't been visited */

    while (node->paths[i].node != NULL)
    {
        if (visited[getNodeIndex(node->paths[i].node)] == 0)
            depthFirstSearch(node->paths[i].node, thisVisited, depth + 1,
                                  node->paths[i].dist);

        i++;
    }

    for (int j = 0; j < depth; j++)
        putchar(' ');
}

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    nodes[0] = newNode("Liverpool");
    nodes[1] = newNode("London");
    nodes[2] = newNode("Manchester");
    nodes[3] = newNode("Norwich");

    addPath(nodes[0], nodes[1], 212);
    addPath(nodes[0], nodes[2], 34);
    addPath(nodes[1], nodes[2], 208);
    addPath(nodes[1], nodes[3], 114);
    addPath(nodes[2], nodes[3], 191);

    int visited[NODES] = {0};

    depthFirstSearch(nodes[0], visited, 0, 0);

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

---

After `malloc()`ing the node and its path array:

```
(gdb) p toReturn
$16 = (node_t *) 0x602010
(gdb) p toReturn->paths
$17 = (struct _path_t *) 0x602030
```

Before the FOR loop:

```
(gdb) p toReturn->paths[0]
$18 = {node = 0x0, dist = 0}
(gdb) p toReturn->paths[1]
$19 = {node = 0x0, dist = 0}
(gdb) p toReturn->paths[2]
$20 = {node = 0x602030, dist = 0} // (I don't understand this value here.)
(gdb) p toReturn->paths[3]
$21 = {node = 0x0, dist = 0}
(gdb) p toReturn->paths[4]
$22 = {node = 0x0, dist = 0}
(gdb) p toReturn->paths[5]
$23 = {node = 0x0, dist = 0}
(gdb) p toReturn->paths[6]
$24 = {node = 0x0, dist = 0}
(gdb) p toReturn->paths[7]
$25 = {node = 0x0, dist = 0}
(gdb) p toReturn->paths[8]
$26 = {node = 0x0, dist = 0}
(gdb) p toReturn->paths[9]
$27 = {node = 0x0, dist = 0}
(gdb) p toReturn->paths[10]
$28 = {node = 0x0, dist = 0}
(gdb) p toReturn->paths[11]
$29 = {node = 0x0, dist = 0}
(gdb) p toReturn->paths[12]
$30 = {node = 0x0, dist = 0}
(gdb) p toReturn->paths[13]
$31 = {node = 0x0, dist = 0}
(gdb) p toReturn->paths[14]
$32 = {node = 0x0, dist = 0}
(gdb) p toReturn->paths[15]
$33 = {node = 0x0, dist = 0}
```

State of `toReturn` before FOR loop:

```
(gdb) p *toReturn
$36 = {
  name = "Liverpool", '\000' <repeats 15 times>, "\021\001", '\000' <repeats 37 times>, paths = 0x602030}
```

It remains unchanged until it unexpectedly changes in the FOR loop when `i = 3`

```
(gdb) p *toReturn
$40 = {
  name = "Liverpool", '\000' <repeats 15 times>, "\021\001", '\000' <repeats 37 times>, paths = 0x0}
```

Comment: These are way worse than the expected ones.

Comment: @Brian What do you mean?

Comment: The failure case (`return -1;`) in `getNodeIndex()` is never handled, just dereferenced.  Handle it regardless of whether it's the source of the segfault.

Comment: I just meant that unexpected segfaults can be a real bummer -- moreso than expected segfaults.  ;)

Comment: Yea. Ideally, control should never reach the (return -1) statement, but in any case I've replaced it with an error message and exit().

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
node_t* toReturn = (node_t*) malloc(sizeof(node_t*));
```

This looks wrong. You need to allocate the size of `node_t` not `node_t *`. While we are at it  , [do not cast malloc](http://c-faq.com/malloc/mallocnocast.html).

Comment: Oh god... yeah thanks, I suspect that's it. How annoying to make such a trivial error!

Comment: So not casting malloc() _would_ warn me in this situation?

Comment: Yep, that should be it. Newbie mistake made by many students. ;)

Comment: Using `malloc(sizeof(*toReturn))` might make it more obvious (and it eliminate the need to change it the name for `node_t` changed, or if the type of `toReturn` changed).